# Frobenius series problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I have:

$$4x^2y'' + (3x+1)y = 0$$

From this the indicial equation is found so that  $$r(r-1)+1/4=0 \Rightarrow r = 1/2 = r_1 = r_2,$$
so the first solution will be of the form:

$$y_1(x) = \sqrt{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{c_kx^k}$$

($y_2$ follows)

but I need to find the power series solution. I tried substituting it in and solving by finding a recursive relation etc, but I cannot seem to get the answer - am I missing something obvious here, or is it just tedious?

Any tips would be appreciated, I have a test tomorrow and I'm having trouble fully understanding Frobenius even with online resources.

Thanks!

fyi, this is the [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNwen.png)

Comment: (whoever is fixing my formulas thank you, I've been looking up the syntax and trying to edit but you beat me to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
y= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^{k+1/2} \\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1/2)(k-1/2) c_k x^{k-3/2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
substitute this into the equation gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(4k^2-1) c_k x^{k+1/2} +3 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^{k+3/2} +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^{k+1/2} =0\\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(4k^2-1) c_k x^{k+1/2} +3 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{k-1} x^{k+1/2} +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^{k+1/2} =0\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (4k^2 c_k  +3  c_{k-1}) x^{k+1/2} =0\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus we have the recurrence $4k^2 c_k  +3  c_{k-1}=0$ for $k \geq 1$ & this has solution $c_k =\frac{(-1)^k 3^k}{k!^2 4^k}$ so the first solution is
\begin{eqnarray*}
y_1(x) = c_0 \sqrt{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!^2 } \left( \frac{-3x}{4} \right)^k.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @Isham Yes ... well spotted

Comment: Thanks! actually not so bad now that I see it.

Comment: nice answer Donald +1